# Python OpenCV waitKeyEx() stops picking up arrow keys after mouse click or tab

Tags: python, linux, opencv

I'm writing a camera viewer for a lab setup.  Much of the display control is done using the keyboard, a couple of things need a mouse.  Anyway, even without a mouse event handler, I see the same issue.

To nudge the region of interest I use the arrow keys.  This works - until I click with the mouse anywhere in the image window (or press tab, but I hadn't noticed that until I started reading about these issues).  Other keys are still picked up fine.

The following code demonstrates it:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
cv2.namedWindow("window", flags=cv2.WND_PROP_AUTOSIZE+cv2.WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL)
img=np.zeros((100,100,3), np.uint8)   

while True:
    cv2.imshow("window", img) 
    key = cv2.waitKeyEx(1) #waitKeyEx returns the ASCII value of the key if there is one, otherwise the key code; 27=Esc.
    # Key codes depend on the backend hence the "or" for arrow keys & F1.  Linux first, Win10 (via VirtualBox) 2nd            
    # process keypresses.
    if (key==65361 or key==2424832):#left
        print ('left')                                    
    elif (key==65364 or key==2621440):#down
        print ('down')                                                            
    elif (key==65362 or key==2490368):#up
        print ('up')                                    
    elif (key==65363 or key==2555904):#right
        print ('right')                                                         
    elif (key == 27):#Esc
        break      
    else:
        if key >0:print ("key with ASCII code  %d not understood"%key)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It will display which key you pressed in the parent terminal window - and stop doing so after clicking - but only for the arrow keys.

This is the image window I get using the above dummy image (note that I'm using XFCE).
[image: Screenshot of blank image window]

And this with the full viewer and a live image from the camera (as the dummy image makes for a very narrow window):
[image: Screenshot of full viewer window]

I have rather a lot of key bindings in my real code, but anyway the arrow keys are the most intuitive for the user.  Note that there are no error messages, it's a silent failure. Is there some way to restore arrow key functionality after mouse events?

Output of `print(cv2.getBuildInformation())` follows. It appears to be using  QT5 not GTK+ (I expected the latter):

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.6.0 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2022-06-07T10:28:59Z
    Host:                        Linux 5.13.0-1025-azure x86_64
    CMake:                       3.22.5
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /bin/gmake
    Configuration:               Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (16 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (31 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (5 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                /usr/lib/ccache/compilers/c++  (ver 10.2.1)
    C++ flags (Release):         -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /usr/lib/ccache/compilers/cc
    C flags (Release):           -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a -L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined  
    Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a -L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined  
    ccache:                      YES
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          /lib64/libopenblas.so Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Test Qt5::Concurrent /usr/local/lib/libpng.so /lib64/libz.so dl m pthread rt
    3rdparty dependencies:       libprotobuf ade ittnotify libjpeg-turbo libwebp libtiff libopenjp2 IlmImf quirc ippiw ippicv

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo python3 stitching video videoio
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java python2 ts
    Applications:                -
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  GUI:                           QT5
    QT:                          YES (ver 5.15.0 )
      QT OpenGL support:         NO
    GTK+:                        NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /lib64/libz.so (ver 1.2.7)
    JPEG:                        libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.2-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         /usr/local/lib/libpng.so (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.4.0)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (58.134.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.76.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.70.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.9.100)
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)

  Parallel framework:            pthreads

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
           at:                   /io/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
              at:                /io/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
    VA:                          NO
    Lapack:                      YES (/lib64/libopenblas.so)
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                /io/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /opt/python/cp36-cp36m/bin/python3.6 (ver 3.6.15)
    Libraries:                   libpython3.6m.a (ver 3.6.15)
    numpy:                       /opt/python/cp36-cp36m/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.13.3)
    install path:                python/cv2/python-3

  Python (for build):            /bin/python2.7

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    /io/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is using Python 3.8.10 on Ubuntu 20.04 (though it will end up on Windows eventually, hence the alternative keycodes).  OpenCV is 4.6.0.

Comment: might be specific to the GTK backend. can't reproduce on Win10, OpenCV v4.6.0. can _you_ reproduce this on Windows, or only on linux?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I'll attempt to reproduce on Windows, though it would be disappointing if it wasn't cross-platform.  Possibly manageable if only this one feature fails.  Windows might have to wait until Monday - my VM at home will take all weekend to update at the rate it's going now

Comment: Note to close voter: There are no error messages; the failure is silent (now made explicit in an edit).  The code given is the minimum that tests (all) the failing keys on major platforms and allows quitting.  The desired behaviour *"Is there some way to restore arrow key functionality after mouse events?"* was already included.  I'm happy to give further detail but you'll need to state precisely what's missing because the reason you gave doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: what does your imshow window look like? screenshot please. maybe it's got hidden/obvious functionality (pan and zoom) -- also `print(cv.getBuildInformation())`

Comment: Thanks @ChristophRackwitz, added both - it's using QT!  2 window screenshots, small/black dummy image as in my minimal code, and a full window

Comment: Qt GUI... yeah that's a problem. the "downgrade" from the "fancy" Qt imshow() window (`WINDOW_GUI_EXPANDED`) to a featureless one (`WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL`) probably doesn't disengage some enhancements. use the scroll wheel on the window. does it start to zoom even though it shouldn't? https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/d46/group__highgui__qt.html

Comment: Yes, nasty uncalibrated pixelated zoom, which is what I'm avoiding with switching between pixel-to-pixel and shrink-to-window in my code.

Comment: "though it would be disappointing if it wasn't cross-platform" -- I certainly wouldn't expect too much consistency (especially in corner cases) between different backends, and unless you're planning to use a custom qt-based window build, that's definitely gonna be the case. Even though there's been work done on HighGUI lately, I'd still consider it flaky, and only good for basic prototyping, where you don't care about weird crap like this. Just recently I fixed a bunch of silly bugs in the Windows backend that were around since at least early 3.x and there's still more to do...

Comment: the win32 trackbars not resizing properly annoyed me too. I just didn't care enough to look into it. -- they're planning to completely redo highgui using a single 2d/3d graphics backend (opengl/vulkan?), so it's decently cross-platform. that's long term though. highgui backends are only as flaky as people can bear. I'm using the win32 backend all the time. for a long time I built OpenCV myself because the opencv-python build (or was it the official C++ build?) contained the Qt fancy backend, which hides some events, as you just noticed. the macos backend had broken trackbars for a long time.

Comment: you could try filing an issue (unless it exists already) to disengage this fancy behavior of the Qt backend when WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL.

Comment: @DanMašek you're right. This seemed like pretty basic usage and functionality. Something that should easily be portable having written a couple of portable GUIs in python 2 without OpenCV. These days most of my work is terminal based. Having left Windows updating overnight I've tested on that this morning and it looks promising.

Comment: You didn't install it in cmake.

Comment: @toyotaSupra can you explain that? your comments often make no sense.